# Append, Concat, Join or Merge Two dataframes with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, append

How do i combine these two dataframes to achieve the desired output from two dataframes that I created with pandas?

df1 =

```
   OBJECTID  Test #
0         1       1
1         2       2
2         3       3
3         4       4
4         5       5
5         6       6
6         7       7
7         8       8
8         9       9
```

df2 = (index is 2 because it was a slice)

```
   ObjectID  Test Number
2  ObjectID  Test Number
```

The left "column" are the indexes and the headers are at the top. I would like the output to be

```
   OBJECTID    Test #
0  ObjectID  Test Number
1         1       1
2         2       2
3         3       3
4         4       4
5         5       5
6         6       6
7         7       7
8         8       8
9         9       9
```

This:

```
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
frame_append = df2[["OBJECTID","Test #"]].combine_first(df1)
```

gives:

```
   OBJECTID       Test #
0  ObjectID  Test Number
1         2            2
2         3            3
3         4            4
4         5            5
5         6            6
6         7            7
7         8            8
8         9            9
```

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you really just looking to rename some columns? Or insert some values?

Comment: I am looking to insert values. I have two dataframes that are created from two separate .csv files.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this.  Reset set indexes first.

```
df2[[1,2]].combine_first(df1)
```

Output:

```
    0         1            2
0  0.0  ObjectID  Test Number
1  1.0         2            2
2  2.0         3            3
3  3.0         4            4
4  4.0         5            5
5  5.0         6            6
6  6.0         7            7
7  7.0         8            8
8  8.0         9            9
```

Comment: I get "KeyError: '[1 2] not in index'"

The index for df2 is actually 2

Comment: What are you column headers?  Are they strings try [['1','2']]?

Comment: You will need to reset_index on `df2 = df2.reset_index()` to place that row at the top of df.  Otherwise it will place that row at index 2 in df.

Comment: I should have specified that the first column in both dataframes is the index and not an actual column in the dataframe. Apologies. Does this change the [1,2]?

Comment: I tired [0,1] and got an error saying 

KeyError: '[0 1] not in index'

Comment: Yes, 1 and 2 in this case are the default column names since they weren't given in the question. If you have actual column names you can use those.

Comment: what does df.head().to_dict() return and what does df2.head.to_dict() return?

Comment: {'OBJECTID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}, 'Test #': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}}

Comment: {'ObjectID': {2: 'ObjectID'}, 'Test Number': {2: 'Test Number'}}

Comment: The first return is df and second is df2

Comment: I have edited the initial question for clarification

Comment: rename df2 columns to match df1, reset the df2 row index and combine first.

Comment: This seems to just insert the row [2] if df2 into [2] of df1 instead of the desired output.

Comment: resetindex on df2

Comment: edited above to show current code. I think I am resetting?

Comment: You have to add df2 = infront o reset index

Comment: Thank You. My mistake on the simple variable error.

Comment: @geojasm if this is what you need , can you consider accept this answer : -)